# Retrieve multiple values by partial key from dynamo db

Tags: amazon-dynamodb, dynamodb-queries

I did look around and it seems like it is not possible to do easily what I need. Which is puzzling I would think this is a common use case, so I just want to double check.

I have data that looks like this:

(PK, SK -> Value)
A, 1 -> ABC
A, 2 -> DEF
B, 1 -> GHI
B, 2 -> JKL
C, 1 -> MNO

I need a way to read the values given a PK. E.g.:

```
getByPK([A, C]) -> ABC, DEF, MNO
```

I have flexibility to define indices or a store data in a different format.

Notes:

1. the dataset is large, so scan is not an option.
2. number of PKs passed to `getByPK` is small and for now I just retrieve each group one by one (`getByPK(A), getByPK(C)`)
3. there is no an overarching property that can be used to group the items and serve as a partition key.
4. I don't ever need to query by sort key.

Essentially I need an equivalent of `SELECT * FROM myTable WHERE PK IN (A, C)` am I correct there isn't one in DDB world?

The only solution I could think of is to organize data as:
A -> [ {1, ABC}, {2, DEF}]
B -> [ {1, GHI}, {2, JKL}]
C -> [ {1, MNO} ]

but that feels like misusing the database.

Answer (score 0):

If you know the full primary key (partition key + sort key), you can use the [BatchGetItem API](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/amazondynamodb/latest/APIReference/API_BatchGetItem.html).

It sounds like the number of PK's you need to fetch is small, so performing multiple query operations (or getItem if you know the full primary key) is a reasonable option.

If you can apply a logical grouping to these items (e.g. fetch items by type, by date created, some combination of attributes, etc), there are other strategies available to you.  However, it's difficult to elaborate without knowing the specifics of your data.